# Set longtable with multicolumn and multirow to page width

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, tabulary, longtabu

I have a long table (see snippet) with the structure you can see in the image next to it (the table is actually much longer, but it's just the same structure over and over, mixing `multicolumn`s and `multirow`s).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}% Para poder poner colores al texto :)
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|ll|ll|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{SQuaRE Norm}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{XXXXXXXXXXXXX}} \\ \hline
\endhead
%
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Characteristic}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Sub-characteristic}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Proposed metric}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Proposed sub-characteristic}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} &
   &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{XXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX} &
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\ \cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{XXXXXXXXX} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{XXXX XXXXXXXXXXX} &
  XXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} &
   &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX} &
  XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \\ \cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{XXXX} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{XXX XX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX} &
  XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{-5}{*}{XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX}} &
  XXXXXXXXX &
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{-} &
  - \\ \hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want it to fit the page width without going past it, but I've tried multiple solutions I've seen over the Internet with no success. I generated this table using this [editor](https://www.tablesgenerator.com), if it means anything. I've also tried things like `tabularx` and `tabu`, but that usually gets me things like.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove all `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}`, it only overwrite column specification in table preamble ...
- Two solution:

  - using `xltabular` package
  - using `tabularray` package (which I prefer)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable, multirow, xltabular}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{  |>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}L
                                |>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}L
                                |L | L| }
\caption{My caption, used \texttt{xltabular}.}
\label{my-label}    \\
    \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{SQuaRE Norm}} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{XXXXXXXXXXXXX}} \\ \hline
\endhead
%
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
\textbf{Characteristic}     
    & \textbf{Sub-characteristic}
        & \textbf{Proposed metric} 
            & \textbf{Proposed sub-characteristic}  \\ 
    \hline
    &   & XXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
            & XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX          \\ 
   \cline{3-4}
    & \multirow{-2}{=}{XXXXXXXXX} 
        & XXXX XXXXXXXXXXX
            & XXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX           \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    &   & XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX
            & XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX          \\ 
    \cline{3-4}
    & \multirow{-2}{=}{XXXX} 
        & XXX XX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX
            & XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX                     \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-9}{=}{XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX}
    & XXXXXXXXX 
        & --    & --                                \\ 
    \hline
\end{xltabular}

%%%%%%%%
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {My caption, used \texttt{longtblr}.},
  label = {my-label},
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {*{2}{X[l]} *{2}{X[2,l]} },
                 row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, c, bg=black!60},
                 row{2}  = {font=\bfseries, c, m, bg=black!30},
                 rowhead=1
                 }
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    SQuaRE Norm
    &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    XXXXXXXXXXXXX 
            &                                       \\
Characteristic
    & Sub-characteristic 
        & Proposed metric 
            & Proposed sub-characteristic           \\
\SetCell[r=5]{c}    XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX 
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    XXXXXXXXX  
        & XXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            & XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX          \\
    &   & XXXX XXXXXXXXXXX
            & XXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX           \\
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    XXXX 
       & XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX
            & XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX          \\
    &   & XXX XX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX
            & XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX                     \\
    & XXXXXXXXX
        & --    & --                                \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

First table need two to three compilation, the second i need only one.

**Addendum:**
In comments you ask for table formatting changes. Request is not entirely clear, so I guess, that you are interested for the second table, like to reduce `baseline` size and vertical distance between cells contents and their borders:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {My caption, used \texttt{longtblr}.},
  label = {my-label},
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {*{2}{X[l]} *{2}{X[2,l]} },
                 row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, c, bg=black!60},
                 row{2}  = {font=\bfseries, c, m, bg=black!30},
                 rowsep = 1pt,                 
                 rowhead=1
                 }
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    SQuaRE Norm
    &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    XXXXXXXXXXXXX
            &                                       \\
Characteristic
    & Sub-characteristic
        & Proposed metric
            & Proposed sub-characteristic           \\
\SetCell[r=5]{c}    XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    XXXXXXXXX
        & XXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            & XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX          \\
    &   & XXXX XXXXXXXXXXX
            & XXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX           \\
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    XXXX
       & XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX
            & XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX          \\
    &   & XXX XX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX
            & XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX                     \\
    & XXXXXXXXX
        & --    & --                                \\
\end{longtblr}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

which produce to my opinion less nice table:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I had tried a lot of solutions from this site with no success, all because I used tablesgenerator.com. Thank you again. Would you know by any chance which parameter should I use to make the table a bit more narrow? Like to make cells "thinner"?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @J.Maria, **(i)** able width is equal to \textwidth as requested in the question. **(ii)** I took a liberty and define page layout by use of the geometry package. You can remove this package or define desired page layout. **(iii)** If you like to have table narrower from `\textwidth`, at first table change `{\linewidth}` to desired width and at second table add option `width=<desired width>` to tabler preamble. It is worth to take a time to read some introductory text how to write table. For example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables or https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf.

Comment: Sorry, it was kinda late when I wrote that, I meant narrower but in height, since I feel some cells can be "squished" a bit more.

Comment: @J.Maria, which vertical distance you like to reduce? Or you mean to use smaller font sizes? Bot is possible, but first please clarify your request/question.

Comment: I might like to try both options if they're not too complicated. Thanks

Comment: @J.Maria, the most complicated is that it is not clear, what you like to have ... see addendum to answer (will appear soon).